# How to replace tabs in java resource files with white-spaces?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, text-indent

I have some ancient resource files containing text, however, there are sometimes tabs and sometimes white-spaces separating e.g.

```
TABLE_NAME        = Table
FIELD_NAME        = Field
COMBOBOX_NAME     = Combo Box
             ^^^^^
```

I would like to replace the tabs where the ^^^ are with spaces. Using **Edit > Convert Indents > To Spaces** doesn't work since it's only for indents. In my case, I have no indents, it's the tabs between that I need to remove.

**- EDIT -**

Right-clicking on my resource file in Project View and selecting *Reformat Code* completely obliterates my code. ALL white-spaces (including newlines) are removed, so afterwards my file looks like this:

```
TABLE_NAME=Table
FIELD_NAME=Field
COMBOBOX_NAME=Combo Box
```

Which is definitely much worse.

Comment: Have you tried `CTRL` + `ALT` + `L` ([Reformat code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformatting-source-code.html)) after selecting the desired [directory of your sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/reformat-code-on-directory-dialog.html) in the _Project_ tool window?

Comment: Yes, it's even worse. I have edited my question.

Comment: Well, the reformat operation follows your defined [code style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html?search=code%20style) (File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> Java or whatever you want to change) which you can tweak to your liking. After deciding what you want it to look like, the you can apply it to your package.

Comment: That did the job, granted I had to specifically change the code style for Properties files. Odd though, the preview function doesn't seem to work, regardless of which checkboxes I mark/unmark, the preview window example stays identical. If you reformat this as an answer we can delete these comments and I can mark you as accepted.

Comment: Done. You're right, the preview for the properties does not seem to work. There is [this issue on their tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163408) which is fixed, but perhaps it's not included in our build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ already support code [reformatting at package/folder level](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformatting-source-code.html) and the default shortcut for this on Windows is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
So if you open you `Project` tool window and select your folder, then either use the key combination above or right-click it and click on *Reformat code*.

[image: Reformat code]

Please be aware that the formatting will follow your defined [code style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html).

To change that go to **File** `->` **Settings** `->` **Editor** `->` **Code style** `->` **Java** or whatever you want to change:

[image: Code style]